# correspondence theorem question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ has order $12$ and $G'$ has order $6$, produced by elements $x$ and $y$ respectively, and $\phi$ maps $G$ to $G'$ which is defined by $\phi(x^n)=y^n$, how is the correspondence exhibited in the correspondence theorem?

Comment: By *correspondence theorem* do you mean [this result](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Correspondence_Theorem_%28Group_Theory%29)?